# Tweetdeck: Is wyUpdate safe?

Tags: tweetdeck

I recently upgraded tweedeck.  When I close tweetdeck now I get a UAC prompt from wyUpdate program by wyDay:

[image]

I can't find anything official on this.  Is this legitimate?  Can someone point me to some official twitter or tweetdeck source that mentions this?

It's just strange I can't find anything official on this anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do believe it is legitimate. I get those updates from time to time as well. I do notice significant changes to my tweetdeck after it updates the program and I don't get any residual slow downs or other changes to my computer.

Here's some information about wyUpdate (wyDay):

http://wyday.com/wyupdate/ (explains what it is)

http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/faq.php (some FAQ's)

**EDIT:**

Also, since the [TweetDeck release notes for v2.0.1](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169897#) mentions wyUpdate by name, I think we can decisively conclude that it is legitimate software.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but still looking for something official or at least more of a consensus.

Comment: Based on the [TweetDeck release notes for v2.0.1](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169897#) which mentions wyUpdate by name, I'd conclude that yes, it is legitimate.

Comment: Thank you @sidran32 exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find.  If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it.